# What is so 'ridiculous' about it?

Tags: word-choice

I came across an article on [BusinessInsider](http://www.businessinsider.in/The-21-Most-Ridiculous-Photos-From-The-Homes-Of-Ukrainian-Government-Officials/articleshow/30954236.cms) which reads -

> The 21 Most Ridiculous Photos From The Homes Of Ukrainian Government Officials

I don't understand what's so [ridiculous](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ridiculous) about it? Is this word being used in a different context here?

In fact, looking at the photographs, I'd have appreciated words like *stunning, wonderful, jaw-dropping, stupendous*.

Comment: Perhaps (I didn't see the photos), they might be ridiculously luxurious.

Comment: An interesting example of how context is everything. In an art museum, or in an ancient cathedral, such opulence might be considered artistic or breathtaking. In a political climate where the powerful are abusing their power and unfairly exploiting the country's wealth for their own personal indulgence, these same ornate furnishings are deemed preposterous or obscene.

Comment: Just hope they get preserved for some decades, and they will _be_ museums :) Look at Versailles :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These photographs come from the private properties of people that were supposedly elected in a democratic way to run a country that belongs to the poorest in Europe.

I certainly would not call it wonderful that these people managed to enrich themselves to the extent of seemingly recreating Versailles during the short period that they were in power. It shows how these people have abused their power to shamefully enrich themselves beyond imagination.

I realise there are people who would admire such effective behaviour, and even call it wonderful. But for most people (and especially the ones that got to pay for it!) this is horrendous.

The pictures are deemed ridiculous, not so much because they inspire you to laugh, but because they are absurd and preposterous. It makes absolutely no sense that these guys were able to build these things while the country remained poor.

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary you link to gives this definition:

> worthy of or exciting ridicule; absurd, preposterous, laughable, or contemptible

It is *preposterous* (contrary to reason or common sense) and *contemptible* (worthy of contempt, despicable) that public servants should exploit their public offices to accumulate the extraordinary wealth which permits them to indulge in such preposterous and contemptible exhibitions of tastelessness.

Comment: BI being the kind of publication it is, I suspect they are using *ridiculous* in the slang sense (*ridic*, if you will): something worthy of *notice* for its outrageousness or excessiveness, but not necessarily of *ridicule* or *contempt*. If I tell my friend that her party was *ridiculous*, I intend it as a compliment.

Answer (score 3):

The article that you link to says, "And he's not the only powerful Ukrainian enjoying a ridiculously luxurious residence." So what the writer meant is that the level of luxury of these officials is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

In this context the meaning of ridiculous should be read as outrageous, which is a synonym.